# Continuation-Passing Style And Concurrency

Tags: javascript, multithreading, haskell, asynchronous, concurrency

I find lots of blogs mention concurrent/non-blocking/asynchronous programming as a benefit of Continuation-Passing Style (CPS). I cannot figure out why CPS provides concurrency, e.g., people mention Node.js is implemented using CPS though JavaScript is a synchronous language. Would someone comment on my thoughts?

First, my naive understanding of CPS is that *wrapping all subsequent code at a point into a function and pass that function explicitly as a parameter*. Some blogs name the continuation function as `return()`, Gabriel Gonzalez calls it a [hole](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/12/the-continuation-monad.html), both of which are brilliant explanations.

My confusion mostly comes from a popular blog article [*Asynchronous programming and continuation-passing style in JavaScript*](http://2ality.com/2012/06/continuation-passing-style.html). At the beginning of the article, Dr. Axel Rauschmayer gives two code snippets, a synchronous program and an asynchronous one in CPS (pasted here for easy reading).

The synchronous code:

```
function loadAvatarImage(id) {
    var profile = loadProfile(id);
    return loadImage(profile.avatarUrl);
}
```

The asynchronous code:

```
function loadAvatarImage(id, callback) {
    loadProfile(id, function (profile) {
        loadImage(profile.avatarUrl, callback);
    });
}
```

I don't get it why the CPS one is asynchronous. After I read another article *[By example: Continuation-passing style in JavaScript](http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/)*, I think maybe there is an assumption to the code: the function `loadProfile()` and `loadImage()` are asynchronous functions by themselves. Then it is not CPS that makes it asynchronous. In [the second article](http://matt.might.net/articles/by-example-continuation-passing-style/), the author actually shows an implementation of `fetch()`, which is similar to `loadProfile()` in the blog earlier. The `fetch()` function makes an explicit assumption of the underlying concurrent execution model by calling `req.onreadystatechange`. This leads me to think maybe it is not CPS that provides concurrency.

Assume the underlying functions are asynchronous, then I go into my second question: can we write asynchronous code without CPS? Think of the implementation of the function `loadProfile()`. If it is asynchronous not because of CPS, why can't we just take the same mechanism to implement `loadAvatarImage()` asynchronously? Assume `loadProfile()` uses `fork()` to create a new thread to send the request and wait for the response while the main thread is executing in a non-blocking manner, we can possibly do the same for `loadAvatarImage()`.

```
function loadAvatarImage(id, updateDOM) {
    function act () {
        var profile = loadProfile(id);
        var img = loadImage(profile.avatarUrl);
        updateDOM (img);
    }
    fork (act());
}
```

I give it a callback function `updateDOM()`. Without `updateDOM()`, it is not fair to compare it with the CPS version -- the CPS version has extra information about what to do after the image is fetched, i.e., the `callback` function, but the original synchronous `loadAvatarImage()` does not.

Interestingly, @DarthFennec pointed out my new `loadAvatarImage()` is actually CPS: `fork()` is CPS, `act()` is CPS (if we explicitly give it `updateDOM`), and `loadAvatarImage()` is CPS. The chain makes `loadAvatarImage()` asynchronous. `loadProfile()` and `loadImage()` do not need to be asynchronous or CPS.

If the reasoning up to here is correct, can I get these two conclusions?

1. Given a set of synchronous APIs, someone coding following CPS will not magically create asynchronous functions.
2. If the underlying asynchronous/concurrent APIs are provided in the CPS style, like CPS versions of `loadProfile()`, `loadImage()`, `fetch()`, or `fork()`, then one can only code in CPS style to ensure the asynchronous APIs are used asynchronously, e.g., `return loadImage(profile.avatarUrl)` will nullify the concurrency of `loadImage()`.

Comment: "The important point is: this is not CPS -- loadProfile() and loadImage() are not CPS functions." I'm not sure what you mean. `loadAvatarImage` _is_ CPS in your example. Sure, `loadProfile` and `loadImage` are not concurrent or CPS. But `fork` is both concurrent and CPS. And because `fork` provides its asynchronicity through CPS, `loadAvatarImage` also must. If `loadAvatarImage` was not CPS here, it would not be asynchronous.

Comment: Great catch, @DarthFennec! I never thought `fork()` is CPS, and `loadAvatarImage()` is CPS actually. Interesting. Let me edit the question a little so that you can write your answer formally. Thank you for helping me understand it a little more!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A Brief Overview of Javascript

Javascript's concurrency model is *non-parallel* and *cooperative*:

- Javascript is *non-parallel* because it runs in a single thread; it achieves concurrency by *interleaving* multiple execution threads, rather than by actually running them at the same time.
- Javascript is *cooperative* because the scheduler only switches to a different thread when the current thread *asks it to*. The alternative would be *preemptive* scheduling, where the scheduler decides to arbitrarily switch threads whenever it feels like it.

By doing these two things, Javascript avoids many problems that other languages don't. Parallel code, and non-parallel preemptively-scheduled code, cannot make the basic assumption that variables will not suddenly change their values in the middle of execution, since another thread might be working on the same variable at the same time, or the scheduler might decide to interleave another thread absolutely anywhere. This leads to mutual exclusion problems and confusing race condition bugs. Javascript avoids all of this because in a cooperatively-scheduled system, the *programmer* decides where all the interleaves happen. The main drawback of this is if the programmer decides not to create interleaves for long periods of time, other threads never have a chance to run. In a browser, even actions like polling for user input and drawing updates to the page run in the same single-threaded environment as the Javascript, so a long-running Javascript thread will cause the entire page to become unresponsive.

In the beginning, CPS was most often used in Javascript for the purpose of *event-driven UI programming*: if you wanted some code to run every time someone pressed a button, you would register your callback function to the button's `'click'` event; when the button was clicked, the callback would run. As it turns out, this same approach could be used for other purposes as well. Say you want to wait one minute and then do a thing. The naive approach would be to stall the Javascript thread for sixty seconds, which (as stated above) would cause the page to crash for that duration. However, if the timer was exposed as a UI event, the thread could be suspended by the scheduler instead, allowing other threads to run in the meantime. Then, the timer would cause the callback to execute, in the same way a button press would. The same approach can be used to request a resource from the server, or to wait for the page to load fully, or a number of other things. The idea is that, to keep Javascript as *responsive* as possible, any built-in function that might take a long time to complete should be part of the event system; in other words, it should use CPS to enable concurrency.

Most languages that support cooperative scheduling (often in the form of *coroutines*) have special keywords and syntax that must be used to tell the language to interleave. For example, Python has the `yield` keyword, C# has `async` and `await`, etc. When Javascript was first designed, it had no such syntax. It did, however, have support for closures, which is a really easy way to allow CPS. I expect the intention behind this was to support the event-driven UI system, and that it was never intended to become a general-purpose concurrency model (especially once Node.js came along and removed the UI aspect entirely). I don't know for sure, though.

#### Why does CPS provide concurrency?

To be clear, continuation-passing style is a method that *can be used* to enable concurrency. Not all CPS code is concurrent. CPS isn't the only way to create concurrent code. CPS is useful for things other than enabling concurrency. Simply put, CPS does not necessarily imply concurrency, and vice versa.

In order to interleave threads, execution must be interrupted in such a way that it can be resumed later. This means the *context* of the thread must be preserved, and later re-instated. This context isn't generally accessible from inside of a program. Because of this, the only way to support concurrency (short of the language having special syntax for it) is to write the code in such a way that the *thread context is encoded as a value*. This is what CPS does: the context to be resumed is encoded as a function that can be called. This function being called is equivalent to a thread being resumed. This can happen any time: after an image is loaded, after a timer triggers, after other threads have had a chance to run for a while, or even immediately. Since the context is all encoded into the continuation closure, it doesn't matter, as long as it runs eventually.

To better understand this, we can write a simple scheduler:

```
var _threadqueue = []

function fork(cb) {
    _threadqueue.push(cb)
}

function run(t) {
    _threadqueue.push(t)
    while (_threadqueue.length > 0) {
        var next = _threadqueue.shift()
        next()
    }
}
```

An example of this in use:

```
run(function() {
    fork(function() {
        console.print("thread 1, first line")
        fork(function() {
            console.print("thread 1, second line")
        })
    })
    fork(function() {
        console.print("thread 2, first line")
        fork(function() {
            console.print("thread 2, second line")
        })
    })
})
```

This should print the following to the console:

```
thread 1, first line
thread 2, first line
thread 1, second line
thread 2, second line
```

The results are interleaved. While not particularly useful on its own, this logic is more or less the foundation of something like Javascript's concurrency system.

#### Can we write asynchronous code without CPS?

Only if you have access to the context through some other means. As previously stated, many languages do this through special keywords or other syntax. Some languages have special builtins: Scheme has the `call/cc` builtin, which will wrap the current context into a callable function-like object, and pass that object to its argument. Operating systems get concurrency by literally copying around the thread's callstack (the callstack contains all of the needed context to resume the thread).

If you mean in Javascript specifically, then I'm fairly certain it's impossible to reasonably write asynchronous code without CPS. Or it would be, but newer versions of Javascript also come with the `async` and `await` keywords, as well as a `yield` keyword, so using those is becoming an option.

#### Conclusion: Given a set of synchronous APIs, someone coding following CPS will not magically create asynchronous functions.

Correct. If an API is synchronous, CPS alone will not make that API asynchronous. It may introduce a level of concurrency (as in the example code earlier), but that concurrency can only exist within the thread. Asynchronous loading in Javascript works because the loading itself runs in parallel to the scheduler, so the only way to make a synchronous API asynchronous is to run it in a separate system thread (which can't be done in Javascript). But even if you did do that, it still wouldn't be asynchronous unless you also used CPS.

CPS doesn't cause asynchronicity. However, asynchronicity *does* require CPS, or some alternative to CPS.

#### Conclusion: If the underlying asynchronous/concurrent APIs are provided in the CPS style, then one can only code in CPS style

Correct. If the API is `loadImage(url, callback)` and you run `return loadImage(profile.avatarUrl)`, it will return `null` immediately and it will not give you the image. Most likely it will throw an error because `callback` is `undefined`, since you didn't pass it. Essentially, if the API is CPS and you decide not to use CPS, you're not using the API correctly.

In general though, it is accurate to say that if you write a function that calls a CPS function, your function also needs to be CPS. This is actually a good thing. Remember what I said about the basic assumption that variables will not suddenly change their values in the middle of execution? CPS solves this issue by making it very clear to the programmer where exactly the interleave boundaries are; or rather, where values might arbitrarily change. But if you could hide CPS function calls inside of non-CPS functions, you would no longer be able to tell. This is also the reason the newer Javascript `async` and `await` keywords work the way they do: any function that uses `await` must be marked as `async`, and any call to an `async` function must be prefixed with the `await` keyword (there's more to it than that, but I don't want to get into how promises work just now). Because of this, you can always tell where your interleave boundaries are, because there will always be `await` keywords there.

Comment: It is very useful to have the scheduler example. This explains how non-blocking is achieved on one CPU core in the cooperative style. CPS helps to achieve it.